# disable the need to accept cookies every time an Iframe is opened

Tags: html, iframe

Hi I am using an iframe in my website, Every time the iframe website is opened the user needs to accept cookies and since this iframe is usually opened multiple times it causes problems. Is there a way to make sure that the user only needs to accept the cookies once and then they disappear?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55858249/how-to-hide-banner-after-click-and-save-with-localstorage#55858300) 
`LocalStorage` provides the two methods `setItem()` and `getItem()` to set and retrieve data. On page load, you can check for the value you set and hide the banner, or if it has not been set yet, register your click handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('cookies-accepted') === '1') {
    $('#CookieBanner').hide();
  } else {
    $("#Accept").click(function() {
      $('#CookieBanner').hide();
      window.localStorage.setItem('cookies-accepted', '1');
    });
  }
});
```

To learn more, [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

**Try it (Does not work on Stack Overflow, so try it after saving the file)**:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('cookies-accepted') === '1') {
    $('#CookieBanner').hide();
  } else {
    $("#Accept").click(function() {
      $('#CookieBanner').hide();
      window.localStorage.setItem('cookies-accepted', '1');
    });
  }
});
</script>
        
    <div id="CookieBanner">
        <div class="agj">
            <div class="agj-content">
                <div class="initial-info">
                    <h2 class="title">Privacy</h2>
                        
                        <p class="message">
                            This website uses cookies to provide you with the best possible service and website functionality, and to provide social media features and analyse the traffic to our website. If you continue to use our website, you agree to our using cookies.
                        </p>
                        
                </div>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <button id="Accept">Accept</button>
                        <a class="link" href="info" title="Get more Information about Cookies and how we use them">Why?</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```